Why is my PSP VFPU assembly function for getting the quaternion of a set of Euler values incorrect?
I'm trying to make a function that takes a 3 long array of Euler values in π/2 radians, and have it give back the a quaternion for rotation. The VFPU assembly is as follows:
.globl psplaVec3RotationQuaternion
psplaVec3RotationQuaternion:
    lv.q r000, 0($a0)            # Load Euler angles
    vfim.s s003, 0.5             # Scale values by 0.5 (Divide by 2)
    vscl.t r000, r000, s003
    vsin.t r001, r000            # Get sine and cosine of each value
    vcos.t r002, r000
    vmov.q c100, c000[z,y,z,z]   # z is the cosine value, and y is sine 
    vmov.q c110, c010[z,z,y,z]
    vmov.q c120, c020[z,z,z,y]
    vmul.q c200, c100, c110      # Multiply all moved values into a single column
    vmul.q c200, c200, c120
    vmov.q c100, c000[y,z,y,y]   # Repeat for second set of numbers
    vmov.q c110, c010[y,y,z,y]
    vmov.q c120, c020[y,y,y,z] 
    vmul.q c210, c100, c110
    vmul.q c210, c210, c120
    vadd.q c220, c200, c210[x,-y,z,-w]
    sv.q c220, 0($a1)            # Return rotation values
    jr $ra

I called the function with the float array [2.0, 1.5, 3.0], which should give me the quaternion [0.6532815, 0.2705981, 0.2705981, 0.6532815] , but gives back the quaternion with the second value negated.
I also noticed that when I convert the incorrect quaternion to a rotation matrix, it appears to be transposed as compared to the correct matrix.
Correct Matrix:
[  0.0000000, -0.7071068,  0.7071068;
   1.0000000,  0.0000000,  0.0000000;
   0.0000000,  0.7071068,  0.7071068 ]

Converted from Incorrect Quaternion:
[  0.0000000, -1.0000000,  0.0000000;
   0.7071065, -0.0000000,  0.7071071;
  -0.7071071,  0.0000000,  0.7071065 ]

